# Copy Feature in postgresql failing when data is in epoch format (org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: date/time field value out of range:)

Tags: postgresql, copy, rdbms

I have a data in my csv file where timestamp field values are in EPOCH format. When I try to insert the csv file into postgres with copy feature I'm getting below error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "1680894075000"
  Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
  Where: COPY source_pr_tbl, line 1, column processing_time: "1680894075000"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processCopyResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1211)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.endCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1016)
```

Is there any way to insert the epoch directly into the postgres without data convertion ?

Any inputs would be helpful here, Thankyou !!!

Comment: No, not possible, COPY can't use any function while processing the input. You could use COPY to upload the data to a staging table, and use that data for an INSERT statement, using a function, to load the data in the target table.

Comment: 1) What is the data type for the column `processing_time`? 2) `select to_timestamp(1680894075000); 05/31/55235 05:50:00 PDT 05/31/55235 05:50:00 PDT` which indicates you actually need `select to_timestamp(1680894075000/1000); 04/07/2023 12:01:15 PDT`. Note the first query did not fail, to me that means something is off in the column defintion.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I'm not preparing any query i'm just passing my csv file to copy function, which doesn't accept timestamp data to be in epoch format it needs timestamp format to be in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Now my problem is i dont know how to convert epoch to required format in nifi flow

Comment: I tried to add UpdateRecord processor and apply the \dob -> ${field.value:toDate():format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}
 but i don't know why this is not working unfortunately

Comment: 1) Postgres accepts more formats then `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` for a `timestamp(tz)` field. It just won't accept an `integer`. 2) Do as @FrankHeikens suggested and `COPY` into a staging table where the field is an `integer` and then do the transformation `to_timestamp(1680894075000/1000)` on moving to final table.

Comment: No this solution doesnt help as my data would be huge, I have to transform from EPOCH to TIMESTAMP format, I tried UpdateRecord Processor to update the timestamp field from epoch to string i'm getting blank output from the processor
@AdrianKlaver

Comment: 1) Then this is a pipeline issue not a Postgres issue. 2) Currently your 'quick' solution is not working, so it maybe worth to try the alternate solution and see how much it slows you down.